# Logback in Azure Websites with PlayFramework

Tags: java, playframework, logback, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to enable Logback in my Playframework application, but it is not quite working at Azure environment, just in my dev's.

I added a file named logger.xml at the /conf folder, just like the [site](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SettingsLogger) says. But when I create a war and upload it to Azure website, it seems to ignore it.

Any idea how to solve it?

I'm using PlayFramework 2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it works on azure you need to place the logger.xml file inside the folder `WEB-INF/classes`.

In my case, I'm using the plugin `com.github.play2war.plugin._` so i created a folder on my project `APP_HOME/war/WEB-INF/classes/logger.xml` and it was automatically added to the war during the compilation.